# correct url() request

Tags: uri, redirection

I need to make a redirect after a customer added something to his cart so I write this:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  array_push($form['#submit'], '_MODULE_redirect_to_products');
}

function  _MODULE_redirect_to_products(&$form, &$form_state){
  global $language ;

  $form_state['redirect'] = url('prodotti', array('language' => $language));
}
```

but this code redirect me to

```
/dev/azzurra/?q=it//dev/azzurra/%3Fq%3Dit/prodotti
```

but I need to redirect to

```
/dev/azzurra/?q=it/prodotti
```

according to the language obviously.

**UPDATE:**
I'm try to use

```
 $form_state['redirect']
```

but if I display this field before modify it I can see this

```
Array
(
    [0] => prodotti
    [1] => Array
        (
            [language] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [language] => it
                    [name] => Italian
                    [native] => Italiano
                    [direction] => 0
                    [enabled] => 1
                    [plurals] => 2
                    [formula] => ($n!=1)
                    [domain] => 
                    [prefix] => it
                    [weight] => 0
                    [javascript] => a97-0F_JBbaSYaN4XQBbFbhCLCysRpSabTcDmQjB73E
                    [provider] => locale-url
                )

        )

    [2] => 302
)
```

but the form redirect me to 'it/testate/name' because the form 'add product' is displayed in a view so I think that the views module override the $form_state['redirect'] after me so the default redirect [and mine one..].

I think I can't use this kind of redirect.. 
How can I achieve this redirect correctly?

Comment: This starts to look like chameleon question :(

Comment: I know.. if I can find a way to use my code [it works redirecting to the wrong url but it redirect! ] it will be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

`$form_state['redirect']` does not take full URL. It takes the same set of parameters `url()` does. In your case it should probably look like this:

```
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  // $path
  'prodotti',
  // $options
  array('language' => $language),
  // $http_response_code
  302,
);
```

Comment: In the form_alter hook?

Comment: @Shyghar I prefer to do it in submit handler, but if it triggers redirection when you want it, leave it be.

Comment: I try to add your redirect code but the form just ignore it redirecting users to the default redirect page.. This form is generating by drupal commerce.

Comment: Are you sure form's submit handler is attached to form itself, not to submit button?

Comment: I don't know. How can I check this?

Comment: `dpr($form)` and just see

Comment: in the dpr I can see multiple form fields [like submit, uid, product_id, quantity.. ] not only the submit button.
I'm updating the question..